# What is the optimal strip size/full stripe size on a RAID 10 array for a database server?

Tags: sql-server, raid, performance, database, ssd

I'm setting up a new SqlServer database server at work. The machine is a HP Proliant DL368 Gen9 with the SSD disks. When trying to create the array, I have to select the stripe/full stripe size. This is my first time setting up a RAID array, I have no idea how to configure these setting for best results. I want to set up one big RAID 10 array on the server using all six SSD drives. The default for both options are the following:

strip/full stripe size: * 256KiB/768 KiB

sectors/track: * 32

What would be the optimal configuration for these two settings? Or should I stick with the default options? Keep in mind this machine will be used as a database server only.